# Javascript validate filename before upload

Tags: javascript, validation

I simply want to validate the filename of the image being uploaded to ensure that it does not have spaces or unusual characters.

This is my latest attempt from searching around, still no luck. Could it be something to do with the path of the file? is it taking this or just the file name into account?

I have this and a check of the extention working server side with php, but I would like a prompt to the user before submitting.

At this point in time im getting the alert pop up even whether i use a file name it should accept or one that it should reject.

JavaScript

```
function validate(elem){
    var alphaExp = /^[a-zA-Z_-]+$/;
    if(elem.value.match(alphaExp)){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert("File name not suitable");
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="filename" id="filename" onchange="validate(this)" /> 
<p><input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a much more complex regular expression for this, because the `elem.value` you are checking won't be something like `image123.jpg` but more something like `C:\fakepath\randomfolder\some other folder\image123.jpg`

You might want to check into this : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/216238/Regular-Expression-to-validate-file-path-and-exten

The exemple you'll find on this page is mostly for documents, not images, but you can twist it a bit to fit your needs like this :

```
^(?:[\w]\:|\\)(\\[a-z_\-\s0-9\.]+)+\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$
```

Comment: Thanks alot. So from this is does seem like my problem was down to the path of the file also being there. I'll have a play about with this. Thanks again

Comment: This doesnt make sense; what would you validate the full string? You need something like elem.value.split("\\").pop().match(/^[a-zA-Z_-]+\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg)$/)

Comment: I get what you're saying, but your solution won't work if there is actually a "\\" in the filename.

Comment: @Leo Thanks alot for your help on this. It worked perfectly. I've recently noticed that it does not work on safari and firefox. I always get a match as they seem to include the file paths when using these browsers.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this function too....

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function getNameFromPath(strFilepath) {
    var objRE = new RegExp(/([^\/\\]+)$/);
    var strName = objRE.exec(strFilepath);

    if (strName == null) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return strName[0];
    }
}
</script>
```

and

```
<script language="javascript">
function Checkfiles() {
    var fup = document.getElementById('filename');
    var fileName = fup.value;
    var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    if(ext == "gif" || ext == "GIF" || ext == "JPEG" || ext == "jpeg" || ext == "jpg" || ext == "JPG" || ext == "doc") {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Upload Gif or Jpg images only");
        fup.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is very very  simple with `test` function

```js
function validate(form){
  if (/\s/.test(form.elements.file.value)) {
    alert(' filename contains spaces. Please rename the file.');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<form onsubmit="return validate(this);">
  <input type="file" name="file" value="" >
  <input type="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Source https://codehurdles.blogspot.in/2017/11/javascript-validate-filename-before.html